# Magento2 get custom dropdown value in checkout page, admin & email

Tags: magento2, drop-downs

Magento2 How to pass custom dropdown value options(Not the dropdown product attribute) from product page to cart page & in admin & email as well?
example -

```
<select>
    <option value="320">kilogram</option>
    <option value="100">Pack</option>
</select>
```

- I want Kilogram or pack whichever option is selected it's option in checkout page, admin & email

How can I achieve this? Thanks